# Django Page not found using simple path

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Im using django version 2.1.4.

Created app 'main' inside my project and trying to get to its urls.py to show sentence "text" under the admin/main/test/

However while admin/ and admin/main/ are working, admin/main/test/ gives error

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/main/test
>
> Using the URLconf defined in statystyki.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> main/
> admin/ [name='index']
> admin/ login/ [name='login']
> admin/ logout/ [name='logout']
> admin/ password_change/ [name='password_change']
> admin/ password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
> admin/ jsi18n/ [name='jsi18n']
> admin/ r/<int:content_type_id>/<path:object_id>/ [name='view_on_site']
> admin/ auth/group/
> admin/ auth/user/
> admin/ main/movie/
> admin/ ^(?P<app_label>auth|main)/$ [name='app_list']
> ```
>
> The current path, admin/main/test, didn't match any of these.

My files:

statystyki/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('main/', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

main/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import test_response

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', test_response),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def test_response(request):
    return HttpResponse('test')
```

Could you help me to find the issue which is causing this? I already added 'main' to installed apps in settings.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the wrong url. Try to remove **`/admin`** from url. 
Hence the url will be **`http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/test/`**

Answer (score 1):

`admin/', admin.site.urls` admin path is only for default app and therefore when you try to retrieve your main app page from it, the error you have countered is get shown. You should try the URL with your include path where it is `path('main/', include('main.urls')),` and then follow with the inside path of the main which is `path('test/', test_response),` Briefly, you should have:

```
http://localhost:8000/main/test/
```